# Convert line to "rectangle snake". Canvas. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, computational-geometry, bspline

May be someone know good **JavaScript** library or framework for canvas drawing.

I have following issue:

*1)* draw some line via free-hand (like Paint/Photoshop pencil)

*2)* need convert line into "rectangle snake" (build a line using rectangles with fixed width)

look at screenshot
[image]

What kind of library will be better to use for this issue? 
May be some kind of library alredy has this functionality?

I mean need following functionality:

- line approximation
- spline separation
- converting line to polygons/shapes/objects

Will be great if someone will help me. Thanks!

Comment: With fixed width, do you mean fixed length of the enclosed curve segment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say in your question, your points can be [turned into a spline](http://scaledinnovation.com/analytics/splines/aboutSplines.html) consisting of a set of cubic Bezier curves. Hint: you might [simplify the point-set](https://gist.github.com/rhyolight/2846020) before calculating the spline of the remaining (fewer) points.

**Here's how to calculate a set of rectangular-ish polygons along a cubic Bezier curve.**

Sidenote: The polygons must be rectangular-ish because it's not possible to create a set of side-connected rectangles along a curved path.

[image]

1. Calculate a set of points along the curve.
2. Using the points in #1, calculate the tangent angle for each of the points.
3. Using the points & angles, calculate perpendicular lines extending outward in both directions from each point.
4. Use the endpoints of the perpendicular lines to build a set of polygons. Each new polygon is built from the prior & current perpendicular endpoints.

**Here is annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// variables defining a cubic bezier curve
var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;
var s={x:20,y:30};
var c1={x:300,y:40};
var c2={x:40,y:150};
var e={x:370,y:170};

// an array of points plotted along the bezier curve
var points=[];
// an array of polygons along the bezier curve
var polys=[];

// plot some points & tangent angles along the curve
for(var t=0;t<=100;t+=4){

  var T=t/100;

  // plot a point on the curve
  var pos=getCubicBezierXYatT(s,c1,c2,e,T);

  // calculate the tangent angle of the curve at that point
  var tx = bezierTangent(s.x,c1.x,c2.x,e.x,T);
  var ty = bezierTangent(s.y,c1.y,c2.y,e.y,T);
  var a = Math.atan2(ty, tx)-PI/2;

  // save the x/y position of the point and the tangent angle
  points.push({
    x:pos.x,
    y:pos.y,
    angle:a
  });         
}

// create polygons that extend on either side of the 
//     original points set
for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
  var p0=points[i-1];
  var p1=points[i];
  polys.push({
    x0:p0.x+20*Math.cos(p0.angle),
    y0:p0.y+20*Math.sin(p0.angle),
    x1:p1.x+20*Math.cos(p1.angle),
    y1:p1.y+20*Math.sin(p1.angle),
    x2:p1.x+20*Math.cos(p1.angle-PI),
    y2:p1.y+20*Math.sin(p1.angle-PI),                
    x3:p0.x+20*Math.cos(p0.angle-PI),
    y3:p0.y+20*Math.sin(p0.angle-PI),
  });
}

// draw the polygons
for(var i=0;i<polys.length;i++){
  var r=polys[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(r.x0,r.y0);
  ctx.lineTo(r.x1,r.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(r.x2,r.y2);
  ctx.lineTo(r.x3,r.y3);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// draw the bezier curve points
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
  ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
}
ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.strokeStyle='red';
ctx.stroke();

function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}


//////////////////////////////////////////
// helper functions
//////////////////////////////////////////

// calculate one XY point along Cubic Bezier at interval T
// (where T==0.00 at the start of the curve and T==1.00 at the end)
function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
  var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
  var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
  return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
  var t2 = T * T;
  var t3 = t2 * T;
  return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
  + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
  + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
  + d * t3;
}

// calculate the tangent angle at interval T on the curve
function bezierTangent(a, b, c, d, t) {
  return (3 * t * t * (-a + 3 * b - 3 * c + d) + 6 * t * (a - 2 * b + c) + 3 * (-a + b));
};
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>"Rectangular-ish" polygons along the red cubic bezier curve.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
```

**Uniform width polygons:**

Again, because they are *rectangular-ish* polygons, you will not be able to get precisely uniform widths. To get semi-uniform widths:

- Calculate many points along the curve (maybe 1000+).
- Use the distance formula to reduce the 1000+ point-set to a point-set with  uniform distances along the curve: `var distance=Math.sqrt( (pt1.x-pt0.x)*(pt1.x-pt0.x) + (pt1.y-pt0.y)*(pt1.y-pt0.y) )`